# Is there a way to execute ```info sources``` command with more than one pattern?

Tags: gdb

When I'm trying to search for sources, and specify both: directory name and base name (or file name pattern - doesn't make any difference) it takes everything after the first option name as a pattern and shows nothing. Is there any special syntax I missed?

```
(gdb) info sources -dirname src -basename stat
Source files for which symbols have been read in:
(dirname matching regular expression "src -basename stat")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, `info sources` takes a maximum of one option, either `-dirname` or `-basename`, and uses basic regular expressions.

If you have access to POSIX commands, you can match multiple patterns by piping the output of `info sources` to `egrep` or `grep -E`, which use extended regular expressions, including alternation.

Here's how to match multiple basenames (assuming pathname components are separated by `/`):

```
pipe info sources | sed 's/, /\n/g' | grep -E '(word1|word2)[^/]*$'
```